# Automatic relevance determination with prior distribution for lengthscale

Tags: gpflow

I'm trying to use GPflow to fit a GP. I would like to use automatic relevance determination and a prior for the lengthscales.

I know how to do both separately:

```py
kernel = gpflow.kernels.SquaredExponential(lengthscales=([10] * X_train.shape[1]))
```

and

```py
kernel.lengthscales.prior = tfp.distributions.Gamma(
    to_default_float(3), to_default_float(0.25)
)
```

...but I would like to do both (so basically a different Gamma distribution as a prior for each feature).

I tried just using both lines of code and there is no error, but the prior does not seem to add or change anything.

How can I combine both these things?

EDIT: I played with it some more and I thought maybe it would not matter that much, as the lengthscales are adjusted during training. However, the starting point of the lengthscales has a significant impact on the accuracy of my model, and they never change dramatically from the starting point.

For instance, initializing with lengthscales = 10 gives optimized lengthscales between 7 - 13, 15 gives 12-18, etc. Initialising with smaller lengthscales such as 0.1 or 1 leads to lengthscales closer to 10.

Still, I think it would be very valuable if it would be possible to set a prior for every feature as to use ARD. I might investigate next if that is (only?) possible using MCMC methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have different prior distributions for each input dimension, too: you just need to define the prior accordingly. For example,

```py
alpha_ard = np.array([3.0, 4.0, 3.0, 3.0, 7.0])
beta_ard = np.array([0.25, 0.4, 0.4, 0.25, 0.25])
kernel.lengthscales.prior = tfp.distributions.Gamma(alpha_ard, beta_ard)
```

Note that the prior now has a `batch_shape` of [5] instead of [] as before.

This does change things, as you can verify with the following simple example:

```py
import gpflow
import numpy as np
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
import tensorflow as tf

num_data = 1
input_dim = 5
output_dim = 1

X_train = np.ones((num_data, input_dim))
Y_train = np.ones((num_data, output_dim))

single_prior = tfp.distributions.Gamma(np.float64(3.0), np.float64(0.25))
ard_equal_priors = tfp.distributions.Gamma(np.array([3.0]*5), np.array([0.25]*5))
ard_different_priors = tfp.distributions.Gamma(np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]), np.array([0.25, 0.1, 0.5, 0.2, 0.3]))

def build_model(prior):
    kernel = gpflow.kernels.SquaredExponential(lengthscales=([1.0] * input_dim))
    kernel.lengthscales.prior = prior
    model = gpflow.models.GPR((X_train, Y_train), kernel, noise_variance=0.01)
    opt = gpflow.optimizers.Scipy()
    opt.minimize(model.training_loss, model.trainable_variables)

m1 = build_model(single_prior)
m2 = build_model(ard_equal_priors)
m3 = build_model(ard_different_priors)
```

`m1` and `m2` end up with exactly the same lengthscales, whereas `m3` is different.

Without using MCMC, the hyperparameters are just point estimates (maximum likelihood [MLE] without setting priors, or maximum a-posteriori [MAP] with setting priors like you did). There are commonly several local optima, so which one you end up in does depend on the initialization. See [this distill article](https://drafts.distill.pub/gp/) for more explanation.